# Paste into a new line and preserve indentation

Tags: indentation

I want a mapping that does it. 
Apparently, it is not that simple.
Because first, it might decide to keep it commented when I press o.
And it behaves differently if it was copied by yy, insists adding additional `<CR>`. 
My best effort so far is this:

```
function! MPf()
    let @+ =substitute(@+,"\<NL>$","",'')
    exec "norm x\"+]P"
endfunction


nnoremap mp o <esc>:s/[^ \t]//ge<CR>:call MPf()<CR>
```

I add a space so that  won't cancel indentation.
I delete every comment like char in a new line.

But some combination of doing y/yy and when on indented line/unindent line originally still cause troubles. And somehow I don't get rid of the additional `\0`.

Comment: Simply `]p` does this.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It only does it if it was copied by `yy`. Although you are right that I could identify this situation and apply `]p` only if it happens.

Answer (score 3):

The command `]p` does almost what you want, except it is not guaranteed to be linewise.

In `tpope/vim-unimpaired` plugin it's already remapped to work linewise only, so if you use it (which I suggest anyway), you get it for free.

Otherwise, you can implement the same trick yourself:

```
nnoremap <silent>]p :call <SID>putline("]p")<CR>

function s:putline(how)
    let l:type = getregtype(v:register)
    call setreg(getreg(v:register), "V")
    execute 'normal! "' . v:register . a:how
    call setreg(getreg(v:register), l:type)
endfunction
```

See plugin's source code for a more complete version.

Comment: It doesn't work linewise.